# RoR: Associations between Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I made a migration between 2 models as a reference (`rails g migration AddAtendimentoToPacientes atendimento:references`).

In my models, I tried to use the following methods for associations:

> paciente.rb

```
class Paciente < ApplicationRecord
    has_many(:atendimento)
end
```

> atendimento.rb

```
class Atendimento < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to(:paciente)
end
```

Rails console output:

```
[1] pry(main)> paciente = Paciente.last
  Paciente Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "pacientes".* FROM "pacientes" ORDER BY "pacientes"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Paciente:0x0000000009928a20
 id: 2,
 paciente_nome: "Maria Lucia",
 paciente_cpf: "28123712283",
 paciente_idade: 25,
 created_at: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 03:30:58 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 03:30:58 UTC +00:00,
 atendimento_id: nil>
[2] pry(main)> consulta = Atendimento.last
  Atendimento Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "atendimentos".* FROM "atendimentos" ORDER BY "atendimentos"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Atendimento:0x000000000b4ef3a8
 id: 2,
 data_consulta: "22/12/2020",
 tipo_consulta: "Microagulhamento",
 valor_consulta: 1500.0,
 is_pago: true,
 profissional: "Rodrigo",
 created_at: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 03:30:58 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 03:30:58 UTC +00:00>
[3] pry(main)> paciente.atendimento << consulta
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `paciente_id`
from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.4.4/lib/active_model/attribute.rb:207:in `with_value_from_database'
```

when I try:

```
paciente = Paciente.last
consulta = Atendimento.last
paciente.atendimento << consulta
```

I want to inform the Rails that the `Patient` model can have several elements (array) within `atendimento_id`, these elements will be collected from the `Atendimento` model / `Atendimentos` table

> Migration's

```
class CreatePacientes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :pacientes do |t|
      t.string :paciente_nome
      t.string :paciente_cpf
      t.integer :paciente_idade

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateAtendimentos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :atendimentos do |t|
      t.string :data_consulta
      t.string :tipo_consulta
      t.float :valor_consulta
      t.boolean :is_pago
      t.string :profissional

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class AddAtendimentoToPacientes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :pacientes, :atendimento, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

> schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_11_17_020521) do

  create_table "atendimentos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "data_consulta"
    t.string "tipo_consulta"
    t.float "valor_consulta"
    t.boolean "is_pago"
    t.string "profissional"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "pacientes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "paciente_nome"
    t.string "paciente_cpf"
    t.integer "paciente_idade"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "atendimento_id"
    t.index ["atendimento_id"], name: "index_pacientes_on_atendimento_id"
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post the migration file that was generated? Did you run it?

Comment: @Matthew Post edited, migrations added. Yes, I performed the migrations with db:migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you can make a one to many relationship with using the below syntax. See [Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association).

```rb
class Paciente < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :atendimento
end
```

```rb
class Atendimento < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :paciente
end
```

When adding a foreign key between one to many tables it is the has_many table (:atendimento) that will store the id of (Paciente). Practically you need to rollback your migration with `rails db rollback` and change your migration file to the syntax below. Read more about [foreign keys here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys).

```rb
class AddPacienteToAtendimentos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :atendimentos, :paciente, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Comment: It's works, thanks! But I cannot understand the theoretical logic of the name of the migration (``AddPacienteToAtendimentos``), why add ``Paciente`` to ``Atendimentos``, shouldn't it be the other way around?